# Tslint.config formatting/beautification in VS code

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, tslint

How to get tslint.config based formatting in VSCode. I tried some extensions and it warns me about code quality, but not format/beautify my code on save

Comment: To format/beautify your code, you might want to use prettier: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=esbenp.prettier-vscode

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a config option for vscode-tslint [`tslint.autoFixOnSave`](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-tslint/tree/master/tslint#configuration-options), which will run the fixes for any rules that have fixes.

As suggested above [prettier](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=esbenp.prettier-vscode) would be a better solution for formatting your code. You'll want to use [tslint-config-prettier](https://github.com/alexjoverm/tslint-config-prettier), to avoid conflicts between them. Allowing prettier to do formatting, and tslint to do any other fixes.

Comment: I'm not convinced prettier is better but this is the right answer regardless

Comment: I don't think this is the right answer. Prettier is not doing anything useful unless unless you want to commit to the style prettier prefers.

Comment: Is there any CLI command for same as prettier has one for formatting if I've missed auto save on my hundred of files till now

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it working with tslint for TS and beautify for HTML.

-settings.json file:
add: `"editor.formatOnSave": true,`
do not have `"editor.defaultFormatter"` set. In fact just comment it out.

Then open User Settings -> search for "html format enable". You must uncheck the checkbox.

After that both worked for me on save